# Can't read value of a .env file in TypeScipt code

Tags: javascript, typescript, dotenv

I'm trying use .env to read the JWT secret and validate my tokens.

My class at this moment is loading the .env and reading the value, after that I can create a token:

```
export default class AuthMiddleware {
  constructor() {
  }

  private async getJWTSecret(): Promise<string> {
    await dotenvSafe.config();
    let JWTSecret = await process.env.JWT_SECRET || "g&n&r1c5&cre7";
    return JWTSecret;
  }

  public async createJWTToken(user: UserModel): Promise<any> {
    const JWTSecret = await this.getJWTSecret();
    let payloadJWTToken: {};
    payloadJWTToken = { userId: user.id, role: "GENERIC", iss: "My Company", iat: 1516239022, aud: "https://www.mycompany.com.br/"};
    let JWTToken = jwt.sign(payloadJWTToken, JWTSecret);
    return JWTToken;
  }
}
```

Now I adding the method to validate the token I'm trying read the .env in the same way:

```
public async checkJWTToken(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<any> {
    const JWKtokenInRequestHeader = <string>req.headers["authorization"];

    try {
      this.getJWTSecret().then(secret => console.log(`Secret: ${secret}`))
      .catch(error => console.log(`An error has occurred: ${error}`));

    } catch (erro) {
      console.log(`Error message: ${erro}`);
    }

    next();
}
```

But I received this error message:

```
Error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getJWTSecret' of undefined
```

I can't undertend why I read this .env in the same way in another method and it worked fine, and now don't work.

Some tip?

Comment: that error message has nothing to do with reading the `.env` from process. It is clearly saying the `this` keyword is undefined when calling `this.getJWTSecret()`. Your scoping is incorrect in that method. I'm guessing because the `checkJWTToken()` method is called as part of a callback.

Comment: Your `this` does not refer to the same context that contains the getJWTSecret method. Also, you are using a `.catch` within a try and catch which will also cause issues, though probably unrelated.

Comment: Thanks guys. I turned the method static and works fine now.